# A $2\times 2$ matrix has eigenvalue $\lambda = 2$ and associated eginvector $[1,-1]$. Find eigenvalue and associated eigenvector for $A^3-2A+4I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

A $2\times 2$ matrix has eigenvalue $\lambda = 2$ and associated eginvector  $[1,-1]$. Find eigenvalue and associated eigenvector for $A^3-2A+4I$

I'm not sure how to do this.

We know

$$Av = \lambda v$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a& b\\ 
c &d 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
-1
\end{bmatrix} = 2 \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
-1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 
-2
\end{bmatrix}$$

So, $$a-b = 2$$
$$c-d = -1$$

But I'm not sure if this is even a step I'm supposed to do? How do I solve this?

Comment: Factor the polynomial?

Comment: Call your eigenvector $v$, calculate $(A^3-2A+4I)v$ using the hint given in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $A^2v=AAv=A(\lambda v)=\lambda Av=\lambda^2v$.

Comment: If I said $\lambda^3 -2\lambda + 4\lambda$, I would get $8$ as the egeinvalue

Comment: How can I get the eginvector though?

Comment: Look at the hint more closely and recall the definition of eigenvector